# Were some users' reputation mis-adjusted?

Tags: support, reputation

I've seen a few users on SO that, even though they have answered many questions and received many upvotes in the past, they have 1 or very little reputation. For one example that I stumbled onto, refer to [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170746/chasbeen) (sorry for picking one in specific, but it serves as  a good example).

In the reputation tab, I can see that he should have around 300 reputation, at least, and I'm pretty sure not ALL of his answers were voted up by the same user, since some answers have them have 4 or 5 votes. How did it happen that he, and other users I have stumbled upon, have so little reputation, when it's not shown how it was lost?

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere, and I'm just wondering.

Comment: I don't know what *did* happen, but what *could* have happened is that one user upvoted all those answers and was then deleted and his rep was recalced.  If he had a sockpuppet account he used to boost his reputation that would explain it, but that's just one possibility.

Comment: Another possibility is that he was whacked with a couple spam flag penalties (worth about -100 rep each). I'm not sure if that shows up on the public reputation record, though.

Comment: Giving away big bounties might also be a source in some cases.

Comment: @Mark: Ok, that's possible I guess. Would that be for spam answers? @jzd: Yes, but then you'd be able to see it in the reputation history.

Comment: There is also the penalty box.

Comment: He has a staggering 34 spam-deleted answers. Every answer that I looked at except the top one links to his website with no disclaimer.

Comment: @mmyers: Ah, I think you've nailed it there. I didn't know that spam posts cost 100 rep.

Answer (score 6):

Per mmyers

> He has a staggering 34 spam-deleted answers. Every answer that I looked at except the top one links to his website with no disclaimer.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't show those spam penalties on `?tab=reputation` so that people don't always have to ask on meta whenever they notice this?